# Running FindBugs Plugin in Eclipse correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, static-analysis, findbugs

I came across FindBugs tool to identify connection leaks and other bugs which are present in my java code.
I installed the plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace.I am using Eclipse Helios.
However even after a very long search I am not able to find any information on what to do next after installing the plugin..
I build my project from eclipse and after that I deploy the application on JBoss server.

I tried by restarting the server and accessing my application but FindBugs shows no bugs at all..Do I need to add any entries in my class path or any jars needs to be added to the build path??
please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is for debugging Javascript, not Java.  (It is plugin for Mozilla.)  I assume that you are referring to Findbugs, not Firebug.

Findbugs is a *static analysis tool*.  Its purpose is to perform a static analysis of your source code looking for code patterns that are likely to cause problems.  It can spot some common patterns that are *likely* causes of resource leaks, but it can't detect all kinds of leaks.

By the sounds of it, you need a different kind of tool - a dynamic storage leak detector.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716597/java-memory-leak-detection-tools for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to install [CheckStyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/). It is like 10 times more awesome than FindBugs.